# Regex Eliminate Vertical Bar/ Pipe Character

Tags: regex, extjs

Using the following regex with the ExtJS library, the intention is to only allow spaces, dollar signs, underscores, alpha and numeric characters. However, for some reason, the vertical bar/ pipe character is allowed as well. I hope someone can tell me what I am missing here. Am I inadvertently escaping one of the vertical bars?

`maskRe:/^[a-z|A-Z|0-9|$|_ ]$/`

Thank you kindly for your time!

Comment: My apologies, being a new member, I missed the option of wrapping to code in tags to display it properly.

Comment: You can edit your question to add the formatting.

Comment: Thank you, edited for other that might reference in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the vertical bars inside your character class. Try the following instead:

```
maskRe:/^[a-zA-Z0-9$_ ]$/
```

Comment: …which usually can be shortened to: `/^[\w$ ]+$/`. I take it as read that the OP actually wants to allow more than one character, so note the quantifier.

Comment: Wonderful, Phil, I thought I had tested that out before, but must have had another character off. I'm new to regex, but certainly realizing how powerful it can be!